# unable to scroll ionic cards horizontally

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll

I want to scroll my ion-card component horizontally but it's not working that way. I've tried every resource on the internet but it's not scrolling horizontally.

Here is my code.

```ts
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100% ; height:400px">
    <ion-card nowrap *ngFor="let id of mydata" >
        <img src="assets/imgs/arpit.jpg"/>
           <ion-card-content>
                <ion-card-title>
                     {{id.name}}
                </ion-card-title>
            <p>
              {{id.regular_price}}
            </p>
           </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-scroll>
```

The output I am getting is like the image below.

[image]

Comment: try `<ion-slides>`

Comment: did it and worked!..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this styles is easy to do [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp)